# How to recognize Finger and authenticate in iPhone

Tags: iphone, fingerprint

How to recognize the user finger for login authentication  and Capture the finger image in iPhone?

Comment: I guess you could use the camera...

Comment: That is impossible. The technology is totally different.

Comment: @Davids: Haha. Looks like you are arguing with yourself!

Comment: @FreeAsInBeer: Heh, interesting. I guess to elaborate on my earlier comment, the OP could _try_ to use the camera.  It probably won't be a very good fingerprint scan, but it would at least be an interesting proof of concept attempt.  Mobile cameras have been used to do some pretty cool stuff as a result of such attempts, so for research alone it's worth some effort.

Comment: I guess that might be possible. I would think you would have to be very still and hold the camera at just the right distance. Seems like it would be very flaky. And detecting the ridges might be pretty difficult. If you need this kind of security in an application, you probably shouldn't be using an iPhone which could be lost or stolen.

Answer (score 3):

The screen that Apple uses is incapable of detecting a fingerprint. It only detects changes in the charge at different points on the screen, allowing you to detect touches, swipes, etc. You can read more here at [howstuffworks](http://electronics.howstuffworks.com/iphone1.htm).